# Unzipping with ZipInputStream and IoUtils.copyStream() freeze

Tags: java, android, freeze, zipinputstream

I'm trying to unzip a File (30 Mb) programmatically, this is my script

```
public void unzip() {

        dirChecker(location);

        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + location+ze.getName());
                //create dir if required while unzipping
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName());

                    IoUtils.copyStream(zin, fout);

                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();
                }

            }
            zin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}



private void dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(location + dir);

    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

the unzipping goes well, until the 24th file in the zip, the application hangs whithout giving any error, simply freeze in the line:

```
 IoUtils.copyStream(zin, fout);
```

no log, no exception trown, nothing... i discovered the right line putting a break point after the try and manually cicling until the 24th file arrive (it's an 1.1mb jpg, i had no trouble extracting with winzip)

any hint?

Comment: You should close resources in `finally` blocks so they are guaranteed to be closed regardless of whether exceptions occur. That is probably unrelated to your problem, though.

Comment: Is IoUtils part of some library or is it something android specific?

Comment: @David Conrad: yes.. i forgot that... but don't solve my problem... :( as i said i have no log message or stackTrace)

Comment: @DieterDP IoUtils is a standard java class (but the apache commons version is more famous)

Comment: Have you verified it's actually related to the file and not the 24th position? Maybe there's some limit on the number of streams you can open at the same time? Or there might be something blocking the output stream - try renaming the file in the zip...

Comment: @DieterDP unfortunately i can't modify the file, is downloaded from a service that i can't touch

Comment: Well, you can still meddle with the downloaded file in order to try and find the problem, no? Once you find the cause of the problem, you can go back to working with the service directly.